# Encoding csv files on opening with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, encoding, utf-8

So i have this csv which has rows like these:

```
"41975","IT","Catania","2016-01-12T10:57:50+01:00",409.58
"538352","DE","Düsseldorf","2015-12-18T20:50:21+01:00",95.03
"V22211","GB","Nottingham","2015-12-31T11:17:59+00:00",872
```

In the current example the first and the third word are working fine but the program crashes when it prints `Düsseldorf`, the `ü` is problematic

I want to be able to get the information from this csv file and to be able to `print` it. Here is my code:

```
def load_sales(file_name):
    SALES_ID = 0
    SALES_COUNTRY = 1
    SALES_CITY = 2
    SALES_DATE = 3
    SALES_PRICE =4
    with open(file_name,  'r', newline='', encoding='utf8') as r:
        reader = csv.reader(r)
        result=[]
        for row in reader:
            sale={}
            sale["id"]=row[SALES_ID]
            sale["country"]=row[SALES_COUNTRY]
            sale["city"]=row[SALES_CITY]
            sale["date"]=row[SALES_DATE]
            sale["price"]=float(row[SALES_PRICE])
            result.append(sale)
```

when I print I print the `result` I get:

```
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp866.py", line 19, in encode                                                   
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]                                                
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xfc' in position 384: character maps to <undefined>
```

So far I have tried: changing the `encoding` value in the open function with `utf-8`, `UTF8` etc., making a print function:

```
def write_uft8(data):
    print(data).encode('utf-8')
```

But this is not a viable way when you have to print list of dictionaries.

Someone told me that the problem is that my python is not set to encode to these messages to utf-8, is that true and how do I change it ?

Comment: This might occur due to the encoding of the input file / data. Are you sure the data is given as `utf-8`? In addition, you can find a complete list of all encodings here: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings I would suggest trying `iso-8859-1` or to use `chardet` module to try to auto-detect file encoding.

Comment: in the example set, problems occur only in the word Düsseldorf in the ü, eveything else is fine

Comment: Your issue is the windows cmd you are running the code from, not because of python

Comment: how can I fix it ?

Comment: Try changing your code page to UTF8 before running ... `CHCP 65001`

Comment: Use something like cygwin that has proper utf-8 support or a decent ide like pycharm, cmd is to put it bluntly, is crap.

Comment: ok, it works, write an answer

Comment: Once your cmd codepage is fixed, you won't need to encode the output of print, as python3 is already using utf-8. The default encoding argument for open() is platform dependent, so you may want to keep that one.

Comment: Off-topic: What your code is doing could be accomplished a lot more easily if you used a [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that when python writes to a stream, it attempts to write text in a fashion that is compatible with the encoding or character set of that stream.

In this case, it appears you are running the command in a Windows console that is set to display Cyrillic text (CP866).  The Cyrillic codepage does not contain a corresponding character for `ü` and thus the string cannot be decoded to an appropriate character for output.

Changing the active codepage of your windows cmd console to `utf-8` should help:

```
$ CHCP 65001
```